# How to redirect to route logout when session timeout in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

i want to `redirect` to `logout route` when `session` has`timeout` in `laravel 5.4`

i try this in `app\exception\handler.php`

```
    if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {                       
         return redirect()->route('logout');
    }
```

but it still not working. what can i do

Comment: I'm not sure you can log someone out if their session has expired

Comment: i want to redirect to logout because when i login and then i keep it till session timeout. When i am refresh the page will show error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: @haakym any help??

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053203/how-to-log-out-of-an-expired-session-in-laravel-5-x)

Comment: @Maraboc okay i try this code in Route  

if (Auth::guest()) {
        return back()->withInput();
    } else {
       
        return redirect('/viewproduct');
    }
it 's work but i need to write it full in all Route. any idea??

Comment: Create a middleware for that and add it to your routes !!

Comment: @Maraboc how to route guest middleware in laravel 5.4

Comment: @Maraboc  
if i write like this in my route  Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () { return redirect()->route('login'); }); it will always return to login when auth guest??

Comment: No, if you want always return to login when auth guest you should simply do `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here !!
});` What exactly you want to achieve ??

Answer (score 0):

When a session is timed out you are essentially not logged in anymore.

Are you protecting your routes where you need the user logged in with the `auth` middleware? I think you are missing that step.

Routes protected by the `auth` middleware are automatically redirected to `/login` (the route can be changed) if the user is not logged in (or timed out).

Check out this part of the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: Yes i done with route protect with auth but i need to write all the same code in all route.
if (Auth::guest()) { return back()->withInput(); } else { return redirect('/viewproduct'); }

Comment: Okay then a follow-up. Where did you place the `if ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException)` in your `handler.php`? It should be in the `render()` method above the `return parent::render` line. Also make sure the correct TokenMismatchException is imported using `use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;`.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the bigger picture but I would double check that you are using the `auth` middleware correctly since you should never end up inside the controller action if there is no valid user stored in the session.

Comment: if i write like this in route 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
   return redirect()->route('login');
});

it will always return to login when auth guest??

Comment: No, please check out the Laravel documentation on how to use the `auth` and `guest` middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#protecting-routes.

This gist is to use the `auth` middleware if you want user to be authenticated to access the route and `guest` if you want them to be unauthenticated.